# Hydrating script gets wrongly compiled | Solidjs | SSR

Tags: webpack, server-side-rendering, babel-loader, solid-js, hydration

I am experimenting with the isomorphic approach for Solidjs.
I followed the documentation quite faithfull: https://www.solidjs.com/guides/server.

Visually, everything seems to be working: my html is rendered in the browser as expected.
However, if the hydration would be successful, I would see a log in the browser. Instead I see an error log.

The server:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(getBasicHTMLSkeleton())
})
```

getBasicHTMLSkeleton:

```
import {renderToString, generateHydrationScript, Dynamic} from "solid-js/web";
import HelloWorld from "../../hybrid/components/HelloWorld";

export const getBasicHTMLSkeleton = () =>  {
    const hello = renderToString(() => <HelloWorld />)
    return `
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title> Solid SSR </title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_index.min.css" />
      <script src="hydrate.js" />
      ${generateHydrationScript()}
    </head>
    <body>${hello}</body>
  </html>
`;
}
```

The HelloWorld component:

```
import {createEffect} from "solid-js";

const HelloWorld = () => {
    createEffect(() => {
        console.log('lel!')
    })

    return <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
}

export default HelloWorld
```

The hydrate.js-script (this script is pulled in at the client-side):

```
import {hydrate} from "solid-js/web";
import HelloWorld from "../hybrid/components/HelloWorld";

hydrate(() => <HelloWorld/>, document)
```

I get the following error in the browser's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.template) is not a function
    at ./src/hybrid/components/HelloWorld.tsx (hydrate.js:25:83)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at publicPath:1:1
    at hydrate.js:3421:3
    at hydrate.js:3423:12
```

The webpack config for compiling the script:

```
const tsAndTsxRuleClient = {
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/i,
    exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: [["solid", {"generate": "dom", "hydratable": true}]],
            },
        },
        {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
        },
    ]
}


const configClient = {
    ...configServer,
    entry: './src/client/hydrate.tsx',
    module: {
        rules: [tsAndTsxRuleClient]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'hydrate.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist-client')
    }
}
```

Finally, the relevant part of the bundled hydrate.js

```
(() => {
  console.log('HYDRATING?');
  (0,solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.hydrate)(() => (0,solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.createComponent)(_hybrid_components_HelloWorld__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"], {}), document); // this code breaks everything
})();
```

Did I miss something?

I tried playing around with different webpack configs

eg: "generate"; "ssr" instead of "dom"

I also triple checked possible syntax mistakes and the documentation.

I also tried other domNodes instead of document, eg:

```
hydrate(() => <HelloWorld/>, helloWorldWrapper)
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I found the solution:

First I was having an webpack configuration error:

```js
const configClient = {
    ...configServer,
    entry: './src/client/hydrate.tsx',
    module: {
        rules: [tsAndTsxRuleClient]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'hydrate.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist-client')
    }
}
```

configServer contained: `{target: node}` while it should be: `{target: web}`
Probably you should avoid merging server & client config like this because of this exact reason.

The other problem was my hydration-script tag: `<script defer src="hydrate.js"/>` should have the async attribute: `<script async src="hydrate.js"/>`.

I suggested to improve the documentation. (https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/1857)

Answer (score 0):

You need to server render your app first then hytrate it on the client. So you need two apps, a NodeJs app that does the server side rendering, and the browser app that does hydration. It appears you have only the latter.

Returning the static html file that you use durig development will not be enough, you need the app stringified into it. You are generating and running hydration script without embedding the parts on your server returned code that is going to be hydrated.

You don't need to wrap hydrate function into an IIFE, you can use them directly. If you are not passing props to the top level component, you can use it directly without the anonymous component:

```js
 hydrate(HelloWorld, document);
```

Here, mounting the top level component directly on to the document is not good because it is a common root which can be modified by other libraries. It is better to have a dedicated html element:

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Now we can use it:

```js
 hydrate(HelloWorld, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I updated the original question to include the server-part. I do run a node-express app and I do get the HTML in my browser, so that part works.
The problem lies in the hydrating script (or the way it gets compiled by babel).

This is the problematic part: hydrate(() => <HelloWorld/>, helloWorldWrapper)

Comment: Try updating libraries to their latest versions and try rendering HelloWorld directly, without the anonymous wrapper. It could be file paths, src="hydrate.js", try using src="/hydrate.js". Instructions and examples work, i tested them, probably its your webpack config.

Comment: Turns out you were right about the  webpack config.